# Get numberOfRowsInSection from another UITableViewController XCode7 Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've a CRUD scheme in a `TableViewController` (A) working fine (with only 1 section and several rows). So I want to implement another `TableViewController` (B) where the number of sections will be the number of rows of the first controller A.

Here's the code of the controller B where I try to access `numberOfRowsInSection` from controller A (`AgrupamientosTableViewController`).

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return AgrupamientosTableViewController.tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
}
```

I get the error: `Expected ',' as a separator`.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: **Never** call delegate methods like `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` by yourself. Get the information from the data source array of the other view controller, that means use the same code as the body of the method.

Comment: There's too many things wrong here to know where to begin. Firstly you need to understand the difference between what a class is and what an object is (which is an instance of a class). Read up about the difference between these. Then you need to understand the lifetime of view controller objects. When B exists, A will have ceased to exist so you can't call it. If B is launched from A, then the number of sections can be passed from A to B in pregareForSegue. If B is not launched from A then you need a meta view controller where the number of sections in A is stored independently from A.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments !!!

Answer (score 0):

I've made changes and it seems to work:

```
 override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Agrupamientos")

        let results = try! managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        let Agrupamientos = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        //print(Agrupamientos.count)
        return Agrupamientos.count
}
```

May be this the correct way to do it?

Thanks!!!